# Need to execute a set of lines infinitely in C#

Tags: c#, serial-port, infinite-loop

What I aim to do is to write infinitely to a serial port until a particular key (say 'Enter') is pressed. With all the search results that have come up, it is possible to only run the set of commands WITHIN the loop, and not transfer control. But my problem is a little different. I issue a write to a serial port in the Form Load. Once the command is sent, the GPS puts out some data that I need to read. I read this using the serialPort_DataReceived event. So, if I run the program once, everything goes according to plan. But if I try to put any of the loops provided on many sites such as, while(true) {} or if (;;) {} or using consolekey, I am not able to transfer control from this particular loop to the data received event of the serial port, and hence unable to listen to incoming data on the serial port.

So, what I need is to write to the serial port, listen to incoming data, run my algorithm to update the form, then come back to the first loop; and re-run the whole sequence until a key is pressed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You.

Answer (score 3):

You need to using threading to have these infinite loops. Start up a [background worker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) thread to do your data reading.

You can then either process your data on your UI (if its simple) or use another thread to collect the data as it comes in and process it.

Another example: [here](http://stuff.seans.com/2009/05/21/net-basics-do-work-in-background-thread-to-keep-gui-responsive/)

Comment: Could you please help me with how to do that. I'm still learning C#, and I'm not really on how to go about it...

Comment: There's a link in there to the MSDN site that gives a very simple tutorial on how to do it. I'd suggest building that, then adapt to your own purposes once you understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Threading tutorial:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740(v=vs.71).aspx

or Google "Threading tutorial c#"

Good previous question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177488/c-threading

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use BackgroundWorker or Thread class. Keep in mind that each thread may directly call methods only of it's own WinForms controls. If you want to avoid Cross-thread exceptions you need to to use the "Invoke" method. For more detailed info and samples go to: http://geekswithblogs.net/DrissZouakBlog/archive/2006/06/20/82513.aspx

sample:

```
BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();

bw.DoWork += (x,y)  
    => 
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if (checkCondition)
            {
                // do sth here -> for example refresh control or 
                this.Invoke(updateUI, new object[] { args }); // // now ‘schedule’ the update for when the Winform (i.e. this) is able to by calling
                break; // if the job is done and you want to terminate the thread
            }
            // maybe put some Sleep here Thread.Sleep(5);
        }
    };

bw.RunWorkerCompleted += (x, y) => // not mandatory!
    {
        // sth
    };

bw.RunWorkerAsync(); // start
```